# Why does Wordpress show a long list of errors although WP_Debug is set to false?

Tags: wordpress, debugging, podscms

I have a Wordpress 3.5 installation with Pods framework.

When a data entry error occurs, I call `pods_error` function of Pods Framework to give error message to the user.

Normally, it works properly in my localhost such as this:

[image]

But the same error gives a very long message in server side such as this:

[image]

This error message is not user friendly.

I set `WP_DEBUG` to `false` in both sides. What else should I check in order to find out the cause of the verbose error messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've already fixed this issue, you can get the latest Pods 2.1.1 at http://pods.io/latest/ which should be released soon. What you are seeing there is a combination of a PHP warning produced by Pods and your X-Debug on your server that formats the errors into HTML.